# How to connect Algolia and @material-ui

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui, jsx, algolia

[This is the documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/#connector-param-provided-refine) of how to create a basic `SearchBox` element from just an input field in Algolia. The problem is, Algolia's ends up looking pretty ugly

That's where material-ui comes in. I have used [`AppBar`](https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/) before which contains a search element, so my thinking was to instantiate `SearchBox` within my `AppBar.js` component, but with material-ui's proprietary `InputBase` (instead of boring html `input`).

I'll paste the code I have so far below but it's refusing to compile with `InputBase` (and more specifically it's associated props) being used to create a custom `SearchBox` element.

**If anyone has any experience with meshing different API's like this or think you might know what's going on, don't hesitate to let me know!**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/Appbar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import {fade} from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { connectSearchBox } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const styles = theme => ({
    root:{
        width: '100%',
    },
    grow:{
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton:{
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    title:{
        display: 'none',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
            display: 'block',
        },
    },
    search:{
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
        '&:hover':{
            backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
        },
        marginLeft: 0,
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
            marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
            width: 'auto',
        },
    },
    searchIcon:{
        width: theme.spacing.unit * 9,
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    inputRoot:{
        color: 'inherit',
        width: '100%',
    },
    inputInput:{
        paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
        paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit,
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 10,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]:{
            width: 120,
            '&:focus':{
                width: 200,
            },
        },
    },
});

function SearchBox({currentRefinement, refine}, props){
    const {classes} = props;
    return(
        <InputBase
            type='search'
            value={currentRefinement}
            onChange={event => refine(event.currentTarget.value)}
            placeholder="Search for Destination by Name, State, and keywords..."
            classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
            }}
        />
    );
}


const CustomSearchBox = connectSearchBox(SearchBox);

function SearchAppBar(props){
    const {classes} = props;
    return(
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" color='inherit' noWrap>
                    title
                    </Typography>
                    <div className={classes.grow}/>
                    <div className={classes.search}>
                        <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                            <SearchIcon/>
                        </div>
                        <CustomSearchBox/>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}

SearchAppBar.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SearchAppBar);
```

(as you can probably tell, I have gone very by the book with respect to documentation - I haven't tried anything special)

[image]

Comment: The search bar on the material-ui docs is hooked up to Algolia. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/docs/src/modules/components/AppSearch.js

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back @JoshWooding but the material-ui docs website implementation has so many dependencies and is frankly beyond the complexity of my application, but thanks for the input. I'm getting hung up on implementing css it seems

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the material ui search box component instead of Algolia's, you can use `connectSearchBox();` to sync the material ui search box and Algolia search box API.

```
import { InstantSearch, connectSearchBox } from "react-instantsearch-dom";
const CustomSearchBox = connectSearchBox(MaterialUISearchBox);
```

Inside MaterialUISearchBox component, you will use the props Algolia provides: `currentRefinement` and `refine()`.

```
        <InputBase
          placeholder="Search…"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
          value={this.props.currentRefinement}
          onChange={(e) => this.props.refine(this.currentTarget.value)}
          searchAsYouType={false}
        />
```

Please check the url for further details about Algolia's custom components.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/